# Return results from a table match on exact number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables A and B, that are in a many to many relationship in a third table. What A want to achieve is get the "repeating" A rows based on B. For example:

```
table A             table B             table A_B
----------          ----------          ----------
1                   A                   1      A
2                   B                   1      B
3                   C                   2      A
4                   D                   2      B
5                                       3      A
                                        3      B
                                        3      C
                                        4      A
                                        4      D
                                        5      A
```

What I want is, when searching table A_B by lets say '1', to get only 2, although 3 has both A and B and 4 has A, same goes for 5 too, it matches A but only A so it should be ignored as well. I've tried some suggestions form similar questions with cross join but I had no luck. I am trying to achieve this with just selects and joins, without stored procedures or temporary tables. Any suggestions is welcomed, thank you.

[Repeat all base table rows for EACH left join row match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147248/repeat-all-base-table-rows-for-each-left-join-row-match)

I want my output to look like:

```
table A_B
----------
2     A
2     B
```

Or if possible it would be even better if it matches the A_id by which the search is being done

```
table A_B
----------
1     A
1     B
2     A
2     B
```

However, the B_id column is not as important so if it is only

```
table A_B           
----------
2
```

or

```
table A_B           
----------
1    
2
```

is acceptable as well.

**EDIT 1:**

Until now this is what I've came up with, although a bit unclean but it gets the expected result

```
select 
    A_id
from
    tableA_B
where 
    A_id in 
    (
        select 
            A_id
        from
            tableA_B
        group by 
            A_id
        having 
            count (A_id) IN (
                select 
                    count (A_id)
                from
                    tableA_B
                where
                    A_id = 1
            )
    ) 
    AND 
    B_id IN (
        select 
            B_id
        from
            tableA_B
        where
            A_id = 1
    )
group by
    A_id
```

Basically process of elimination, step by step. It would be ideal if it took only one step.

**EDIT 2:**

I'm sorry I left out some important information, my B values can be repeated for instance

```
table A             table B             table A_B
----------          ----------          ----------
1                   A                   1      A
2                   B                   1      B
3                   c                   2      A
4                   D                   2      B
5                   AB                  3      A
6                                       3      B
                                        3      C
                                        4      A
                                        4      D
                                        5      A
                                        6      AB
```

so using XML path may return incorrect values. Because in my case it will return 6 as well which is incorrect. I apologies for leaving out this information.

Comment: Can you show what the expected output should look like?

Comment: I just edited the question. I hope it's clear enough

Comment: Why upto A B only for 2? Why not C D? What is the logic behind that?

Comment: I need to prevent overlapping... so of an exact same structure ... this is only the first level, I will go one level deeper, but if I solve it here, it will be similar if not identical. Solving my problem on code level is always a possibility, but I would like to try to solve it on database level if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other solution which use `INTERSECT` could be:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA_B (A_id INT, B_id VARCHAR(8))
GO

INSERT INTO tableA_B VALUES
(1,'A'),(1,'B'),(2,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'A'),(3,'B'),(3,'C'),(4,'A'),(4,'D'),(5,'A')
GO

DECLARE @x INT = 1;

SELECT A_id FROM tableA_B ab1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT B_id FROM tableA_B
    WHERE A_id=@x
) ab2 ON ab1.B_id=ab2.B_id
GROUP BY ab1.A_id
HAVING COUNT(*)=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA_B WHERE A_id=@x) 

INTERSECT

SELECT A_id FROM tableA_B ab1
JOIN (
    SELECT B_id FROM tableA_B
    WHERE A_id=@x
) ab2 ON ab1.B_id=ab2.B_id
GROUP BY ab1.A_id
HAVING COUNT(*)=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA_B WHERE A_id=@x) 

DROP TABLE tableA_B
GO
```

Comment: This is also transferable in Oracle if I'm not mistaking?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it should work in Oracle too. I think, there is only GO command which come from T-SQL but it could be achive other way in Oracle. The main solution should be universal for SQL.

Comment: NIce! I marked it as a solution and I really like that is general SQL

Comment: Nice script.@veili_13,what is general sql ?do you want it to use in both oracle and sql server.If no then there is nothing like general script,only performance matter.and with due respect,above script will perform poorly and is hard to debug.

Comment: General means Standard SQL. Of course, when looking at performance there could be done even some improvements. But question wasn't about well-performanced query. At this point we don't have enough informations to talk about performance in this case (indexes, ability to change structure).

Comment: I am sorry I cannot, or at least I do not know how to,  accept both answers... Because I actually do need it for oracle and SQL Server, so I ended up using both. the XML Path is great for SQL Server, but I used this for Oracle, because I need to have support for oracle as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 declare @A_B table(col int,col2 varchar(30))
 insert into @A_B VALUES
 (1 ,'A') ,(1 ,'B') ,(2 ,'A') ,(2 ,'B') ,(3 ,'A') ,(3 ,'B')
 ,(3 ,'C') ,(4 ,'A') ,(4 ,'D') ,(5 ,'A'),(6 ,'AB')

 declare @i int=1
 declare @007 char(1)='-'
 ;with CTE as
 (
 select col,col2
 ,(select @007+col2 from @A_B y 
 where col=x.col for xml path(''))ConcateCol
 from @A_B x
 --where col=@i
 )

 select col,col2 
 from cte c
 where 
 exists(select * from cte c1 
 where  col=@i and c.ConcateCol=c1.ConcateCol)
```

you can further maniplate to get whatever desire output

Comment: This is actually pretty good, and theoretically is the answer to my question, at least the one I posted... I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough I didn't think it thorough and I've left some important information out. I'll edit it.

Comment: I made the edit .... Sorry for the inconvenience. I want to get every record every record from A, that it's connections in A_B match the same for a certain  A_id, in this case 1.

Comment: Yes right after the edit I thought of this as well. This will actually help me much more, because I can concatenate the 2nd level. I just need to check the performance between this and my query, however I think that this will keep things much cleaner.

Comment: Short and clean=performance ok.Though I am not aware about real table and other thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
;With tableA(ID)                     
 AS
 (            
Select 1 uNION ALL                          
Select 2 uNION ALL                          
Select 3 uNION ALL                           
Select 4                                     

)                                      
 , tableB(VAL)
 As
 (                           
SELECT 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C' UNION ALL
SELECT 'D'
)
SELECT ID,VAL  FROM
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID)AS Seq     FROM tableA
CROSS JOIN tableB
)Dt
WHERE ID In (SELECT Id From tableA where id in(1,2) ) AND Dt.Seq<3
```

OutPut

```
table A_B
----------
1     A
1     B
2     A
2     B
```

Comment: no one guarantees that exact sequence.... and I need to use the inner  table A_B to know the connections between A and B, not just cross join and take first couple of rows. This is making them match... I need to find out if they DO match.